# Is it possible to figure out which smart contract array is being accessed out of bounds using ethers.js?

Tags: typescript, solidity, ethers.js

I'm calling a smart contract function with ethers.js and getting `Uncaught (in promise) Error: cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit`

I know it's an array accessed out of bounds because of the panic code:  `"data":"0x4e487b710000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000032"`

However, the `stack` doesn't contain anything related to my contract or functions.

Is there a way to get ethers to log which function is breaking in it's simulation of the transaction?

I've looked in the docs for both and can't find a way to do this, but I'm sure it must be possible, even if I have to monkey-patch something.